# Missing `client_secret` when running offline tests using firebase-functions-test

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using [firebase-functions-test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test) to unit test my cloud functions. The test is configured to run an offline test, but still, when accessing the test firestore, I get an authentication error: `Failed to parse refresh token file: Error: Refresh token must contain a "client_secret" property.`. What can cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging in the code of `firebase-functions-test` and `firebase-admin`, when initializing `firebase-functions-test` for offline mode, it still uses the [gcloud application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application). If you have ever installed and used gcloud, this lives in `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`.

I had a setup from an old project on GCP that was logged in as a service account instead of an authenticated user, hence I had the default credentials setup, but it did not contain the `client_secret` required by `firebase-admin`. I simply logged for application default with `gcloud auth application-default login`. This solves the issue.

Still a bit baffled by the fact that the *offline* mode requires authentication. I haven't tested with an invalid, yet correctly formatted application default credentials.